# How to brew install node.js with Intl?

Tags: node.js, homebrew, intl

I was expecting that `Intl` object was included by default in node v0.12, but when I install node via brew it is not:

```
$ node -v
v0.12.2
$ node 
> console.log(Intl)
ReferenceError: Intl is not defined
```

How can i get the Intl object when installing nodejs via brew? I've seen I can do `brew install node --with-icu4c`, but it seems it install the whole ICU set – while I'd like to install only the [small set](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Intl#full-icu-vs-small-icu), which includes the full Intl API only with english.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you considered using the regular [Node.js download](https://nodejs.org/download/) for OS X?

Comment: well i'd like to know if it is possible with brew :) I could also try with `nvm`.... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`$ brew install node` installs the *small set* for `Intl` by default.

See: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/node.rb#L45-L49

Use `$ brew install node --with-full-icu` in order to install the *full set*.

```
$ node -v
v0.12.2
$ node 
> console.log(Intl)
{}
undefined
```

Try running `brew update` and install again.

Comment: fyi... The Github link is no longer valid.